# How to define an array[object] parameter correctly in the query string - OAS 3.0

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-editor

I have a few issues with an array[object] query string definition in OpenAPI 3.0.3:

```yaml
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: find
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: object
                  minItems: 1
                  maxItems: 1
                  properties:
                    $match:
                      type: object
                      description: To specify conditions to filter the result.
                      properties:
                        name:
                          type: string
                          description: Name of the desired import
```

1 - Even though I have specified that the array can only have 1 item, Swagger UI allows me to add multiple items.

2 - It seems that Swagger UI doesn't encode the content properly or the way I want it. When I call my function in my code, I pass the parameter after stringifying (`JSON.stringify()`) and it is sent like below in the URL:

```
[{%22$match%22:{%22name%22:%22ffghhhjjj%22}}]
```

which is deserialized correctly: `[{"$match":{"name":"ffghhhjjj"}}"]`

But when I see the URL in Swagger UI, it is different:

```
https://.../api/contact-service/v1/imports?find=%5B%22%7B%5C%22%24match%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22name%5C%22%3A%5C%22ffghhhjjj%5C%22%7D%7D%22%5D&limit=2&skip=0
```

This is how the parameter looks like after decoding:

```
["{\"$match\":{\"name\":\"ffghhhjjj\"}}"]
```

As you can see, it has sent the array item as string as it should be an object or that the whole value should have been in string that it can be deserialized correctly on the server side.

3 - Another problem is that even though I defined the `description` for my object's properties, Swagger UI doesn't show it. Defining parameters under `components` also won't show them as it does for the schemas. Any idea that how I can give the user hints about different properties in my parameter object? I need description to explain different ways that the user can fill up the filter. I.e., "name" can be specified in different formats for filtering:

```json
{"name": "item-name"}
```

to just items with the specified name), OR:

```json
"name": {"$in": ["name-1","name-2"]}
```

to get all items that their names matches one of the specified names.

I have tried to place `minItems` and `maxItems` in the different locations but didn't work. The current location doesn't give me any errors. Also, I have tried to remove the `content` and `application/json` properties but didn't make any changes.